# Zend tutorial on my site? May I?

Tags: zend-framework

can someone help me? I would like to share on my site some kind of zend tutorial how to make website from start to finish with Zend framevork. Do I need a license for it and whether the law is violated? whether there is a link to a document where it says? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own tutorial on how to build a site using Zend, then you don't have to worry about it since it's your own IP. But if you're copy pasting fro someone else's website or source then it might be a problem. This depends on how they've chosen to share the license. This restriction can range the whole spectrum from 'copy paste and sell if you want' to "don't  even refer to parts of it"

Comment: JohnP is right. Just a short note - that there is no restriction on using Zend Framework code ;)